# Set SparklineGroup variable for customization

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a group of column `sparklines` at the location `A1:A4` that are bound to the source data in the range `Sheet2!B1:E4` as per following code:

```
Sub sparktry()
Range("$A$1:$A$4").SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkColumn, SourceData:= _
 "Sheet2!B1:E4"
End Sub
```

I would now like to customize these sparkines. Just taking a simple example The series color is being changed to display the columns in red instead of default color. After going through SO and searching on google, I could make it work with the following code.

```
Sub Sparktest()
Dim mySG As SparklineGroup
Set mySG = Range("$A$1:$A$4").SparklineGroups.Add(Type:=xlSparkColumn, SourceData:= _
 "Sheet2!B1:E4")
With mySG
    .SeriesColor.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With
End Sub
```

It works fine and changes series color to Red. My question is on the following code line:

```
Set mySG = Range("$A$1:$A$4").SparklineGroups.Add(Type:=xlSparkColumn, SourceData:= _
 "Sheet2!B1:E4")
```

I am able to get success by writing this code-line in this way only. Since I have already created sparklines in the first sub , what is proper code syntax for setting `mySG` or it requires to be this way only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sparklinegroups):

> "Use the SparklineGroups property of the Range object to return an
>   existing SparklineGroups collection from its parent range."

In short, after you've created the sparklines, you can access them through their parent range. In your case, this might be something like: `Set mySG = Range("A1:A4").SparklineGroups.Item(1)`

Below is what I could figure out from your code, the macro recorder and documentation (see comments in code).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SomeSparklines()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        ' Refer to the sparkline group as soon as you create it.
        With .Range("$A$1:$A$4").SparklineGroups.Add(Type:=xlSparkColumn, SourceData:="B1:E4")
            .SeriesColor.Color = vbYellow
        End With

        ' Loop through existing sparkline groups on Sheet1
        ' gaining access to the sparkline group via
        ' the variable you're looping with.
        Dim sparkGroup As SparklineGroup
        For Each sparkGroup In .Cells.SparklineGroups
            sparkGroup.SeriesColor.Color = vbRed
        Next sparkGroup

        ' Manipulate a specific sparkline group in
        ' cell A1 of worksheet Sheet1. For me, this manipulates
        ' the entire group (not just the sparkline in cell A1)
        With .Range("A1").SparklineGroups.Item(1)
            .SeriesColor.Color = vbBlack

            ' Do whatever stuff needs doing....
            With .Points.Highpoint
                .Visible = True
                .Color.Color = vbGreen
            End With
            With .Points.Lowpoint
                .Visible = True
                .Color.Color = vbRed
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your suggestion regarding `mySG` is good and it works well. Thanks a lot. Also nice of you to provide a sample program to elaborate additional properties.